# SQL query: join the result of a union all query

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query below:

```
select SUM(Amount) Amount 
from
    (
        select Amount from IncomeSource1
        union all
        select Amount from IncomeSource2
    ) inc
```

Now I need to filter the results of this table based on some type that is in a different table. Let's say the the connection would be like this:

```
select Amount 
from IncomeSource1 ic1
     left join IncomeType it on it.id = ic1.id
where it.IncomeType = 1
```

I am trying this below but no luck, I still get all the sum of amounts.

```
select Id, SUM(Amount) Amount 
from
    (
        select Id, Amount from IncomeSource1
        union all
        select Id, Amount from IncomeSource2
    ) inc
    left join IncomeType it on it.id = inc.id and it.IncomeType = 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, remove `id` from the `select`:

```
select SUM(Amount) as Amount
from (select Id, Amount from IncomeSource1
      union all
      select Id, Amount from IncomeSource2
     ) inc left join
     IncomeType it
     on it.id = inc.id and it.IncomeType = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your statement is that you have a `LEFT JOIN` which will always include all rows on the left side of the join.

If you are doing `A LEFT JOIN B ON ...` this will *always* return all rows in A. If there is no match between A and B, the column values for B will be NULL.

What you need instead is an `INNER JOIN`, which will only return rows for which there is a match between A and B in `A INNER JOIN B ON ...`. In your case this would only return rows in A that satisfy the corresponding income type in B.

---

If you want the sums grouped by Id:

```
select Id, SUM(Amount) Amount 
from
    (
        select Id, Amount from IncomeSource1
        union all
        select Id, Amount from IncomeSource2
    ) inc
    inner join IncomeType it on it.id = inc.id and it.IncomeType = 1
group by id;
```

---

If you want the sum for all Id's:

```
select SUM(Amount) Amount 
from
    (
        select Id, Amount from IncomeSource1
        union all
        select Id, Amount from IncomeSource2
    ) inc
    inner join IncomeType it on it.id = inc.id and it.IncomeType = 1;
```